# custom select option not working in angular but worked in html,css template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, drop-down-menu

**script.js**

```
const select = document.querySelectorAll('.selectBtn');
const option = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
let index = 1;

 select.forEach(a => {
a.addEventListener('click', b => {
    const next = b.target.nextElementSibling;
    next.classList.toggle('toggle');
    next.style.zIndex = index++;
})
})
option.forEach(a => {
a.addEventListener('click', b => {
    b.target.parentElement.classList.remove('toggle');
    
    const parent = b.target.closest('.select').children[0];
    parent.setAttribute('data-type', b.target.getAttribute('data-type'));
    parent.innerText = b.target.innerText;
})
})
```

**call.component.html**

```
<div class="select">
      <div class="selectBtn" data-type="callType">Show all calls</div>
      <div class="selectDropdown">
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot none"></span>Show all calls</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot open"></span>Open</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot pending"></span>Pending</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot wrap"></span>Wrap</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot covered_n_c"></span>Covered not called</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot covered"></span>Covered & called</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot time_change"></span>Wrap time change</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot c_dispatch"></span>Cancelled by dispatch</div>
        <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot c_patient"></span>Cancelled by patient</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

this script.js file's code is perfectly working in HTML, CSS template. but when I put it into the angular project. it's not working. need solution. advance thanks :)

Comment: It is working for me in an Angular application [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-morning-9gid8?file=/src/app/app.component.ts). Can you share the error that you are getting?

Comment: @HarshSaini there is no error. but my custom select is not working in angular which worked in my html, css template

Comment: Can you check the `link` I mentioned above, if your code is not working like that then in that case you will need to share more detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

#### In AngularJS the idea is to avoid manipulating the DOM directly

Instead, you set Javascript variables and use `ng-if` to switch on or off elements, or `ng-class` to switch on or off classes.

I am not completely certain what you are trying to achieve but here is a simple piece of code that will at least do the work of the first button. You can expand it to do what you want the dropdown buttons.

Note that no JS or DOM manipulation is needed (at least for this simple level of task).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script><script> const app = angular.module("myModule", []);</script>


<div ng-app  class="select">
  <button class="selectBtn" data-type="callType" ng-click="showDropdown=true">Show all calls </button>
  <div class="selectDropdown" ng-if="showDropdown">
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot none"></span>Show all calls</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot open"></span>Open</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot pending"></span>Pending</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot wrap"></span>Wrap</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot covered_n_c"></span>Covered not called</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot covered"></span>Covered & called</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot time_change"></span>Wrap time change</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot c_dispatch"></span>Cancelled by dispatch</div>
    <div class="option" data-type="callType"><span class="dot c_patient"></span>Cancelled by patient</div>
  </div>
</div>
```